# when we can see an easy simble zipping dll for vb6

Tags: vb6

I dream by code like this

Declare Function ZipFolder Lib "zipeasy.dll"

```
(SourceFolder,DistZipeName)
Private sub Command1_Click()
ZipFolder "C:\MyFolder\", "C:\MyZipdeFolder.zip")
End Sub
```

Many years I try to do this but no thing happen
all similar solution is very complicated 
why and why and why there is no easy solution like what I suggest here?

Comment: It could happen if someone writes a wrapper for the win32 zip api .... oh, maybe someone has already done something like that: google: "vb6 zip source"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `ZipArchive` project - *A single-class pure VB6 library for zip with ASM speed*

First download and add [`cZipArchive.cls`](https://github.com/wqweto/ZipArchive/blob/master/src/cZipArchive.cls) to your VB6 project then you can use this `ZipFolder` function

```
Private Function ZipFolder( _
            SourceFolder As String, _
            DistZipeName As String, _
            Optional LastError As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo EH
    With New cZipArchive
        If Not .AddFromFolder(SourceFolder & IIf(Right$(SourceFolder, 1) <> "\", _
                "\", vbNullString) & "*.*", Recursive:=True) Then
            LastError = .LastError
            GoTo QH
        End If
        If Not .CompressArchive(DistZipeName) Then
            LastError = .LastError
            GoTo QH
        End If
    End With
    '--- success
    ZipFolder = True
QH:
    Exit Function
EH:
    LastError = Err.Description
    Resume QH
End Function
```

There are certainly a lot more things you can do with this class (like listing files in a zip, extracting files, showing progress of the operation, compression to memory only, AES encryption levels) and you can find more samples in the `README.md` in the [repo's root](https://github.com/wqweto/ZipArchive) or in the source code of [`vbzip`](https://github.com/wqweto/ZipArchive/tree/master/test/vbzip) command-line utility that can compress/extract zip archives and more

```
VbZip 0.2.3 (c) 2017-2018 by wqweto@gmail.com (12.1.2018 17:15:52)

Usage: vbzip.exe <command> [-options...] <archive_file> [files]...
e.g. vbzip.exe a backup.zip doc1.txt reports*.xls

Commands:
  a           add files to archive
  l           list archive contents
  t           test archive integrity
  x           extract files from archive

Options:
  -r          recurse subfolders
  -e          include empty folders
  -m LEVEL    compression level [default: 6]
  -o OUTPUT   output folder to extract to
  -i          no percentage indicator
  -y          assume yes to all questions
  -p PASSWORD password used to encrypt/decrypt files
  -mem METHOD encryption method
  -so         output to stdout
  -si NAME    input from stdin zip to NAME in archive
```